# I need help creating a new Arraylist from 2 separate Arraylists

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, max, min

I need to populate my totalprices ArrayList but have no idea how. Basically I need to take the prices ArrayList and the quantities ArrayList and multiply them. Then take the values and add them to the totalprices ArrayList. Then find the min and max of the totalprices. I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure this out. Please help. Thanks!

My code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Project01 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();//Declare the array lists that will be used.
    ArrayList<String> types = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Double> prices = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Integer> quantities = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Double> totalprices = new ArrayList<Double>();
    int count = 0;//Set the counter to zero.
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);//Establish the scanner so user input can be properly read.
    String database = getFile(in);//Setting the file name variable from the method below that asks the user for the file's name.
    try {
        File file = new File(database);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Product Summary Report");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------");
        while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
            getTitle(titles, inputFile.nextLine());
            getQuantity(quantities, inputFile.nextInt());
            inputFile.nextLine();
            getPrice(prices, inputFile.nextDouble());
            inputFile.nextLine();
            getType(types, inputFile.nextLine());
            System.out.println("Title: " + titles.get(count));
            System.out.println(" Product Type: " + types.get(count));
            System.out.println(" Price: " + prices.get(count));
            System.out.println(" Quantity: " + quantities.get(count));
            System.out.println();
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Total products in database: " + count);
        Integer index = getLargestQuantityTitle(quantities);
        System.out.println("Largest quantity item : " + titles.get(index) + " (" + types.get(index) + ")");
        ArrayList<Double> highestTotalDollarAmount = getTotalprices(quantities, prices);
        Double highestTotalDollarAmount = getHighestDollarAmount(totalprices);
        System.out.println("Highest total dollar item: $" + highestTotalDollarAmount);
        Integer index2 = getSmallestQuantityTitle(quantities);
        System.out.println("Smallest quantity item: " + titles.get(index2) + " (" + types.get(index2) + ")");
        System.out.println("Lowest total dollar item: ");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------");
        inputFile.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("There was a problem reading from " + database);

    }
    in.close();
}
private static String getFile(Scanner inScanner) {
    System.out.print("Enter database filename: ");
    String fileName = inScanner.nextLine();
    return fileName;
}
private static void getTitle(ArrayList<String> titles, String title) { //This method is creating the array list of the titles from the input file.
    titles.add(title);
}
private static void getType(ArrayList<String> types, String type) { //This method is creating the array list of the types from the input file.
    types.add(type);
}
private static void getPrice(ArrayList<Double> prices, double price) { //This method is creating the array list of the prices from the input file.
    prices.add(price);
}
private static void getQuantity(ArrayList<Integer> quantities, int quantity) { //This method is creating the array list of the quantities from the input file.
    quantities.add(quantity);
}
private static Integer getLargestQuantityItem(ArrayList<Integer> quantities){ //This method is determining the maximum value within the quantities array list.
    return Collections.max(quantities);
    }
private static Double getHighestPricedItem(ArrayList<Double> prices){ //This method is determining the maximum price within the prices array list.
    return Collections.max(prices);
}
private static Integer getHighestTotalDollarItem(ArrayList<Integer> prices){ //This method is determining the maximum total value, basically the highest quantity of the item multiplied by it's price.
    return Collections.max(prices);
}
private static Integer getSmallestQuantityItem(ArrayList<Integer> quantities){ //This method is determining the minimum value within the quantities array list.
    return Collections.min(quantities);
    }
private static Integer getLargestQuantityTitle(ArrayList<Integer> quantities){
    int index = 0;
    Integer largestQuantityMainVariable = getLargestQuantityItem(quantities);
    for (int i = 0; i < quantities.size(); i++) {
        if (quantities.get(i) != null && quantities.get(i).equals(largestQuantityMainVariable)) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
private static Integer getSmallestQuantityTitle(ArrayList<Integer> quantities){
    int index2 = 0;
    Integer smallestQuantityMainVariable = getSmallestQuantityItem(quantities);
    for (int i = 0; i < quantities.size(); i++) {
        if (quantities.get(i) != null && quantities.get(i).equals(smallestQuantityMainVariable)) {
            index2 = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return index2;
}
        private static ArrayList<Double> getTotalprices (List<Integer> quantities, List<Double> prices){
    ArrayList<Double> totalprices = new ArrayList<Double>();
    for (int i = 0; i < quantities.size(); i++) {
           totalprices.add(quantities.get(i) * prices.get(i));
      }
      return totalprices;

}
private static Double getHighestDollarAmount(ArrayList<Double> totalprices){ //This method is determining the maximum price within the prices array list.
    return Collections.max(totalprices);
}

}
```

Output should look like:

```
Enter database filename: proj1_input.txt

Product Summary Report
------------------------------------------------------------
Title: The Shawshank Redemption
    Product Type: DVD
    Price: 19.95
    Quantity: 100

Title: The Dark Knight
    Product Type: DVD
    Price: 19.95
    Quantity: 50

Title: Casablanca
    Product Type: DVD
    Price: 9.95
    Quantity: 137

Title: The Girl With The Dragon Tattoo
    Product Type: Book
    Price: 14.95
    Quantity: 150

Title: Vertigo
    Product Type: DVD
    Price: 9.95
    Quantity: 55

Title: A Game of Thrones
    Product Type: Book
    Price: 8.95
    Quantity: 100

-----------------------------------------------------------------
Total products in database: 6
Largest quantity item: The Girl With The Dragon Tattoo (Book)
Highest total dollar item: $[1995.0, 997.5, 1363.1499999999999, 2242.5, 547.25, 894.9999999999999]
Smallest quantity item: The Dark Knight (DVD)
Lowest total dollar item: Vertigo ($547.25)
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Input File (.txt file):

```
The Shawshank Redemption
100
19.95
DVD
The Dark Knight
50
19.95
DVD
Casablanca
137
9.95
DVD
The Girl With The Dragon Tattoo
150
14.95
Book
Vertigo
55
9.95
DVD
A Game of Thrones
100
8.95
Book
```

Comment: I don't see where you're calling `getTotalprices`.

Comment: @rgettman I don't need to I don't think because I'm calling getHighestDollarAmount instead.

Comment: You should revise your code implementation. You should have one YourClass containing name, type, price, quantity and totalprice and one single List<YourClass>.

Comment: @SeumasFrew You haven't added any values to `totalPrices` by the time you call `getHighestDollarAmount`, but the only thing that adds any values to `totalPrices` is `getTotalPrices`.

Comment: @rgettman I added getTotalprices(quantities, prices); into the main method to call it, but it's still not working correctly.

Comment: Did you assign the return of `getTotalPrices` to `totalPrices`?

Comment: @rgettman I believe so, the return of totalprices is in the getTotalPrices method. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Did you code `totalPrices = getTotalPrices(quantities, prices);` anywhere?

Comment: No, does that need to be in the getTotalprices method or the main method?

Comment: @rgettman I got it to print the arraylist of the total prices. I don't need the whole array, just the max out of that array. I'll edit the output so you can see what it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Edited to include knutknutsen's answer in the comments below as well as an example implementation for the OP.

Have you considered using a HashMap for this? A HashMap is a List Object that stores 2 objects inside of it. In the below example code, I will be using a String as the "Key" (which will be the title of the movie being indexed) and a created class called StockInfo as the "Object". Then you only need a reference to the title saved somewhere or passed to the class used.

Something like

```
public class Project01{
     static HashMap<String, StockInfo> movies = new HashMap<String, StockInfo>();
     static StockInfo movieWithMaxPrice = new StockInfo();
     static StockInfo movieWithMinPrice = new StockInfo();
     static StockInfo movieWithMaxQuantity = new StockInfo();
     static StockInfo movieWithMinQuantity = new StockInfo();

     public static void main(String[] args){
          int counter = 0;
          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
          String database = getFile(in);
          try{
              File file = new File(database);
              Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
              System.out.println();
              System.out.println("Product Summary Report");
              System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
              while(inputFile.hasNextLine()){
                   StockInfo movieInfo = new StockInfo();
                   getTitle(movieInfo, inputFile.nextLine());
                   getQuantity(movieInfo, inputFile.nextInt());
                   inputFile.nextLine();
                   getPrice(movieInfo, inputFile.nextDouble());
                   inputFile.nextLine();
                   getType(movieInfo, inputFile.nextLine());

                   /**This works because we over-rode the toString 
                     *call that java makes on an object when we try to 
                     *print out the object to the console.
                     */
                   System.out.println(movieInfo);
                   System.out.println();

                  /**The last thing we do is save the created  
                    *StockInfo to the saved HashMap
                    */
                   movies.put(movieInfo.getTitle(),movieInfo);
              }
              System.out.println("------------------------------------");
              System.out.println("Total products in database: "+movies.size());
              System.out.println("Largest Quantity item: "+movieWithMaxQuantity.getTitle()+" "+movieWithMaxQuantity.getQuantity());
              System.out.println("Highest total dollar item: "+movieWithMaxPrice.getTitle()+" $"+movieWithMaxPrice.getPrice());
              System.out.println("Smallest Quantity Item: "+movieWithMinQuantity.getTitle()+" "+movieWithMinQuantity.getQuantity());
              System.out.println("Lowest total dollar item: "+movieWithMinPrice.getTitle()+" $"+movieWithMinPrice.getPrice());
          } catch(IOException e){
              System.out.println("There was a problem reading from "+database);
          }
     }

     /**This method will return the fileName that is housing the 
       *database, which is provided to provided through an in console 
       *input from the user
       */
     private static String getFile(Scanner inScanner){
         System.out.print("Enter database filename: ");
         String fileName = inScanner.nextLine();
         return fileName;
     }

     /**This is a re-written method from the OP code, to read the line 
       *in the database file and fill the created StockInfo class with 
       *the title
       */
     private static void getTitle(StockInfo si, String lineToRead){
         si.setTitle(lineToRead);
     }

     /**This is a re-written method from the OP code, to read the line 
       *in the database file and fill the created StockInfo class with 
       *the quantity. This method also compares the given quantity 
       *with the saved quantities above Max and Min
       */
     private static void getQuantity(StockInfo si, int quantity){
         si.setQuantity(quantity);
         if(movieWithMaxQuantity.getQuantity()<quantity){
               movieWithMaxQuantity = si;
         }
         if(movieWithMinQuantity.getQuantity()>quantity){
               movieWithMinQuantity = si;
         }
     }
     /**This is a re-written method from the OP code, to read the line
       *in the database file and fill the created StockInfo class with
       *the price. This method also compares the given price with the
       *max and min StockInfo objects saved at the top of the class, 
       *to see if this is higher or lower then those. If it is
       *then is saves the new StockInfo object at its respective place
       *so that we always have a pointer towards the max and min
       */
     private static void getPrice(StockInfo si, double price){
         si.setPrice(price);
         if(movieWithMaxPrice.getPrice()<price){
              movieWithMaxPrice = si;
         }
         if(movieWithMinPrice.getPrice()>price){
              movieWithMinPrice = si;
         }
     }

     /**This is a re-written method from the OP code, that takes the
       *next line in the database and assigns it to the StockInfo as
       *its type
       */
     private static void getType(StockInfo si, String lineToRead){
         si.setType(lineToRead);
     }   

   }

/**This is the created class that will be used with the information
  *that gets provided
  */
class StockInfo{
    private String title = "";    //saved reference to the title
    private String type  = "";    //saved reference to the type
    /**saved reference to the price, pre filled at -1 to avoid null pointer exception*/
    private double price = -1;    
    /**saved reference to the quantity available, pre filled at -1 to avoid null pointer exception*/
    private int quantity = -1;


    /**This is the constructor, which needs nothing in this case*/
    public StockInfo(){} 

    /**This is the setter for our saved title string above*/
    public void setTitle(String title){
         this.title=title;
    }    

    /**This is the setter from our saved type string above*/
    public void setType(String type){
         this.type=type;
    }

    /**This is the setter for our saved price integer above*/
    public void setPrice(double price){
         this.price=price;
    }

    /**This is the setter for our saved quantity integer above*/
    public void setQuantity(int quantity){
         this.quantity=quantity;
    }

    /**This is the getter for the title*/
    public String getTitle(){
         return this.title;
    }

    /**This is the getter for the type*/
    public String getType(){
         return this.type;
    }

    /**This is the getter for the saved price*/
    public double getPrice(){
         return this.price;
    }

    /**This is the getter for the saved quantity*/
    public int getQuantity(){
         return this.quantity;
    }

    /**Overriding the toString call and making it return the info needed*/
    @Override
    public String toString(){
         return "Title: "+title+" Type: "+type+"  Price: "+price+" Quantity: "+quantity;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

I think that would be the best for you. Then you can pull the movie you're looking for by the name and it will have the price with it.

Comment: A `HashMap` would be better used with a class representing the stock items, like `HashMap<String, StockItem>`, because if he want to access e.g. the prices by movie name he would need an other `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to multiply corresponding elements in two lists, you do it the obvious way. There are no tricks involved.

```
for(int k = 0; k < prices.size(); k++) {
    totalprices.add(prices.get(k) * quantities.get(k));
}
```

Comment: How would you take the results and add them to a new arraylist?

Comment: I have that code in my program in the getTotalprices method.

Comment: It doesn't need to be called. And if I'm wrong, please show me how.

Comment: @SeumasFrew If it's not called, then the code in it doesn't run - like any other method.

Comment: I added getTotalprices(quantities, prices); into the main method to call it, but it's still not working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Like the answer of @immibis already said, there is no magic multiplying two lists (assuming same length). But I would suggest you to rethink your approach:

Instead of maintaining several list you should create a single class which represents a stock item. With that, you only have to maintain one list.

Like this:

```
public class Project {

  public static class StockItem  {
    public String name;
    public double price;
    public int quantity;
    // ....
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<StockItem> stockList = new ArrayList<>(); // <> works with Java 7+ 

    // make new items
    StockItem newItem = new StockItem();
    newItem.name = nameFromInput;
    newItem.price = priceFromInput;
    // etc.

    // adding it to list
    stockList.add(newItem);

    List<Double> totalPrices = computeTotalPrices(stockList);
  }

  public static List<Double> computeTotalPrices(List<StockItem> stockList) {
    List<Double> totals = new ArrayList<>();
    for (StockItem item : stockList) {
      total.add(item.quantity * item.price);
    }
    return totals;
  }
```

This should make it easier for you to maintain the context of items, prices, quantities etc.

Note that the class in my code has much room for improvement (or rather design flaws), but it will do the trick. Anything more and you would need more knowledge about designing classes etc. And I'm not sure if you already have that. (if you have, I can revise my answer ;D)

Answer (score 0):

the most elegant solution as I think is

```
public class Order {
    public String name;
    public double price;
    public int quantity;

    public double getTotal(){
      return  price*quantity;
   }
}

public class ReportProvider {
   public double getMin(List<Order> orders){
      double min = double.MaxValue;
      for(Order order : orders) {
          double total = order.getTotal();
          if(total < min) // same in max just use > instead
          {
            min = total;
          } 
      }
    return min;
  }
}
```